# can gdb show the variable being destructed?

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

Example:

```
#include <assert.h>

int v = 0;

struct Foo {
    Foo() { ++v; }
    ~Foo()
    {
        --v;
        assert(v != 1); // artificially stop the debugger here
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo a; // assert in destructor here?
    Foo b; // assert in destructor here?
    Foo c; // assert in destructor here?
    return 0;
} // main()
```

This code asserts. I think the debugger should be able to tell me which line/instance of Foo is asserting, but it only shows that it's exiting the scope of `main()`:

```
#6  0x00007ffff7d9ee96 in __GI___assert_fail (assertion=0x555555556019 "v != 1", file=0x555555556010 "main.cpp", line=8, 
    function=0x555555556004 "Foo::~Foo()") at ./assert/assert.c:101
#7  0x000055555555521c in Foo::~Foo (this=<optimized out>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at main.cpp:8
#8  0x00005555555551b6 in main () at main.cpp:17
(gdb) f 8
#8  0x00005555555551b6 in main () at main.cpp:17
17      } // main()
```

**I know the culprit is `b`, but how can I make gcc tell me?**

Is this just a missing feature or is there somethig more fundamental preventing debuggers from showing this information?

If I add a scope for each instance it becomes clear, but I don't think I should have to recompile.

```
int main()
{
    Foo a;
    {
        Foo b;
        {
            Foo c;
        }
    } // <-- backtrace of the assert shows this line
    return 0;
}
```

The same problem exists for members of a class:

```
class Bar {
    Foo a;
    Foo b;
    Foo c;
};
```

---

[EDIT] What I'd really like to see is the debugger stepping back to the line with `Foo c;` when it returns from main(), then `Foo b;` etc. Just like what happens in the following example, where the debugger steps through the Baz() lines one at a time before finally entering func().

```
    func(Baz(),
         Baz(),
         Baz());
```

Comment: Which line is line 17?  It looks like gcc has optimised out the destructor call and inlined the call to `assert` instead.

Comment: @PaulSanders line 17 is the closing brace of main(). I'm compiling with `-Og -g` but I get the same result for `-O0 -g` (edit: actually, this=0x7fffffffdb36, but still no line number for the variable being destructed)

Comment: OK.  Might be worth inspecting the code generated by the compiler at Godbolt.

Comment: @PaulSanders https://godbolt.org/z/vrdcPT3vE - there are three separate calls to `Foo::Foo()` nicely matching the line declaring the instances. Then three separate calls to `Foo::~Foo()`. Based on the colors they all reference the line with the closing brace, which matches what I see in `gdb`. It'd be nice if gcc could instead point them back to the declarations.

Comment: it probably just how function are processed (they do not show which variable they're invoked on, for example, when via pointer). note one can also invoke destructor dynamically or manually.

Comment: @jozxyqk: See the same [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/Yxh17Mn6x) with gcc, there the debug info of each destructor matches the objects. I think this was intentionally changed, because it was distracting in a debugging session if when stepping through, it suddenly jumped back up to the object declaration lines.

Comment: @ssbssa interesting, I was about to say this looks like a compiler bug.  Do you have a link to where this was intentionally changed?  Because that looks like a real step backwards for debug functionality, for exactly the reason given here.

Comment: @Andrew: I think it's [gcc bug 88742](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88742).

Answer (score 0):

> but how can I make gcc tell me?

You can't (at least not directly) -- it has no idea that you are interested in this. But you can give each instance of `Foo` a name it to print the value of `this` and the name in both constructor and destructor.

You could also get this info from GDB:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
44      ./nptl/pthread_kill.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
#1  0x00007ffff7e55d2f in __pthread_kill_internal (signo=<optimized out>, threadid=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#2  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=<optimized out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
#3  0x00007ffff7f9ee70 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7df1472 in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
#5  0x00007ffff7df1395 in __assert_fail_base (fmt=<optimized out>, assertion=<optimized out>, file=<optimized out>, line=<optimized out>, function=<optimized out>) at ./assert/assert.c:92
#6  0x00007ffff7dffdf2 in __GI___assert_fail (assertion=0x555555556015 "v != 1", file=0x555555556010 "t.cc", line=10, function=0x555555556004 "Foo::~Foo()") at ./assert/assert.c:101
#7  0x0000555555555200 in Foo::~Foo (this=0x7fffffffd81e, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at t.cc:10
#8  0x0000555555555183 in main () at t.cc:20

(gdb) fr 8
#8  0x0000555555555183 in main () at t.cc:20
20      } // main()
(gdb) info locals
a = {<No data fields>}
b = {<No data fields>}
c = {<No data fields>}
(gdb) p &a
$1 = (Foo *) 0x7fffffffd81f
(gdb) p &b
$2 = (Foo *) 0x7fffffffd81e   <<=== match for this in frame 7
```

This of course requires that `this` isn't optimized (as it is in your stack), *or* that you print the value of `this` in the destructor.

> [EDIT] What I'd really like to see is the debugger stepping back to the line with Foo c; when it returns from main(), then Foo b; etc.

A compiler *could* in theory do that, but (I suspect) this will be exceedingly confusing to most end-users: "why is the *destructor* being invoked when I am simply constructing Foo?".